# Removing images mentioned in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to construct a path for each image defined in images list and remove it if it exists,currently am hardcoding path for each image mentioned in imagelist below..is there an easier way to implement this?

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call,Popen, PIPE

def main ():
    images=['test1.img','test2.img','test3.img']
    ROOT="/local/mnt/workspace"
    target="wc3123"
    #Construct ROOT + "/out/target/product/" + target + "/test1.img 
    #for each image mentioned in imageslist remove if it exist"
    test1= ROOT + "out/target/product/" + target + "test1.ming"
    check_call("rm -rf %s" %test1,shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you looking to specify filenames on the command line?  If so, have a look at `sys.argv`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv  I also recommend you look at `os.unlink` to delete files instead of spawning processes: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.unlink

Comment: @zigg - no,thats not what I want...what i am asking is if there is an easier way (in a loop may be) to construct the paths and remove them if they exists

Comment: look at glob http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: why do you want to call 'rm -fr'? There is os.unlink()

Comment: What is the problem here? Unlikely writing a loop and checking if the file exists and then remove it? This is a three liner...where do you need help here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over your `images` list of filenames like so:

```
def main ():
    images=['test1.img','test2.img','test3.img']
    ROOT="/local/mnt/workspace"
    target="wc3123"
    for image in images:
        #Construct ROOT + "/out/target/product/" + target + "/test1.img 
        #for each image mentioned in imageslist remove if it exist"
        test1= ROOT + "out/target/product/" + target + "/" + image
        check_call("rm -rf %s" %test1,shell=True)
```

I recommend a few other cleanups as well, such as using [`os.unlink`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.unlink) to remove the files instead of constructing a string to be passed to the shell (which is unsafe), parameterizing your constants so they can be replaced, and using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of concatenating pathnames:

```
import os

def main(images, root='/local/mnt/workspace', target='wc3123'):
    for image in images:
        os.unlink(os.path.join(root, target, image))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(['test1.img', 'test2.img', 'test3.img'])
```

Comment: +1 for `unlink()/remove()`, I also like parameterizing all the variables.

Comment: @zigg - can os.unlink be used to remove directories also?

Comment: No, but you could use `shutil.rmtree` for that case: http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree